# How to reshape a GraphQL (via Hasura) query response?

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have a `CHAT_MESSAGE_FRAGMENT` that returns all the message data from my Hasura graphql api.

However, the Gifted Chat react-native component requires the data in a specific structure so I'm attempting to convert it with the query below.

I'm able to alias all the top level data but can't figure out how to add a nested level of data.

I'm guessing it isn't possible but I thought I'd ask in case I'm missing something.

```js
const GIFTED_CHAT_GROUP_MESSAGES_QUERY = gql`
  query chatGroupMessages($chatGroupId: Int!) {
    chat_message(
      where: { to: { id: { _eq: $chatGroupId } } }
    ) {
      _id: id,
      # user: {
      #   _id: from.id,     <== How do I add
      #   name: from.name,  <== this secondary level?
      # },
      text: message,
      image: image_url,
      createdAt: created_at,
      system: message_type,
    }
  }
  ${CHAT_MESSAGE_FRAGMENT}
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have `chat_message.user_id -> users.id` foreign key constraint set up, you'll also need to alias the `from` object in addition aliasing any of its nested fields:

```
const GIFTED_CHAT_GROUP_MESSAGES_QUERY = gql`
  query chatGroupMessages($chatGroupId: Int!) {
    chat_message(
      where: { to: { id: { _eq: $chatGroupId } } }
    ) {
      _id: id,
      from: user: {
        _id: id,
        name
      },
      text: message,
      image: image_url,
      createdAt: created_at,
      system: message_type,
    }
  }
  ${CHAT_MESSAGE_FRAGMENT}
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

The secondary level of data is basically [nested object queries](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/nested-object-queries.html) in Hasura. You can nest any number of queries as long as a relationship has been created.

In this case, assuming the `chat_message` table has a `user_id` field, you can establish a foreign key constraint for `chat_message.user_id -> users.id`, where `users` is a table with `id` as primary key.

Once the foreign key constraint is created, Hasura Console automatically suggests relationships. Here `user` would be an object relationship in `chat_message` table.

Here's the official docs link for [Creating a relationship](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/relationships/create.html#creating-relationships)

Comment: Thanks @praveenweb. We already had the relationship. Bob's answer specifically gets at the problem. 